Abraham\TwitterOAuth uploading video fails with
I am using Abraham\TwitterOAuth package via composer. Version 7.0.0
Uploading images is fine and posting plain text works but the moment I go to upload a video it fails. The video is MP4 and when I call the status on it, it says 100% succeeded however adding it to a tweet fails. The error I get is
Error posting tweet: {"errors":[{"parameters":{"media.media_ids":["1803210409970634753"]},"message":"Your media IDs are invalid."}],"title":"Invalid Request","detail":"One or more parameters to your request was invalid.","type":"https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/2\/problems\/invalid-request"}
The issue I have with this is the video is uploaded successfully and validated. After reading a number of articles, people say you need 'additional_owners' which I am including but it still does not resolve the issue of posting the video.
This is a snip of my code with all my logging so you can see I am losing my mind.
\Log::info($mediaUrl);

        // Create a temporary file and get its path
        $tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'twitter_upload');

        \Log::info('Temp File Path: ' . $tempFile);

        // Open the URL and the temporary file
        $source = fopen($mediaUrl, 'r');
        $destination = fopen($tempFile, 'w');

        \Log::info('Source: ' . $source);
        \Log::info('Destination: ' . $destination);

        // Copy the source to the destination
        stream_copy_to_stream($source, $destination);

        \Log::info('Stream copied');

        // Close the resources
        fclose($source);
        fclose($destination);

        \Log::info('Resources closed');

        //upload the media to twitter
        $connection->setApiVersion(1.1);
        if ($activity->type === 'image') {
            $media = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => $tempFile]);
        } elseif ($activity->type === 'video') {
            //get the media type
            $mediaType = mime_content_type($tempFile);

            $media = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => $tempFile, 'media_type' => $mediaType, 'media_category' => 'tweet_video', 'additional_owners' => $userTwitterId], ['chunkedUpload' => true]);
        }

        if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() !== 200) {
            \Log::info('Error uploading media to twitter: ' . json_encode($connection->getLastBody()));
        }

        \Log::info('Media uploaded to twitter');
        \Log::info($media->media_id_string);

        //remove all the html tags from the description
        $activity->description = strip_tags($activity->description);
        //create a new line and add the link to the activity
        $activity->description .= "\n\n" . route('show', $activity->uuid);

        if ($activity->subscriber) {
            $activity->description .= "\n\n" . 'Subscribers Only!';
        }

        $connection->setApiVersion(2);

        $params = [
            'text' => $activity->description,
            'media' => ['media_ids' => [$media->media_id_string]],
        ];

        $connection->post('tweets', $params, ['jsonPayload' => true]);

        if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() !== 201 || $connection->getLastHttpCode() !== 200) {
            \Log::info('Error posting tweet: ' . json_encode($connection->getLastBody()));
        }

        // Delete the temporary file
        unlink($tempFile);

so we are clear, this code is way more complicated than I think it needs to be but I went from what I thought would work to breaking it down into super small chunks to find the issue. Unfortunately I am at a loss when it comes to the POST('tweets') at the end failing with the error above.
Anyone got any experience with this?
Oh and in case I didn't mention, the video is MP4 9MB total size

For a simple upload, you might not need 'additional_owners'.  It may be necessary to include logic to verify the video's processing status prior to tweeting. So, you can easily pinpoint the issue.
